# Mongo greater than BigInt

Tags: mongodb

I have collection with subscriptions, every subscription has a special id that i store as a string because it's a BigInt:

```
[{sub_id:"223211232421412323324235435645356"},{sub_id:"223211232421412323324235435645357"},{sub_id:"223211232421412323324235435645358"}]
```

i need to get subscriptions between range, for example, i need to get all subscription that grater than **"223211232421412323324235435645356"** and less than **"223211232421412323324235435645358"**, the code i came up with looks like this:

```
let long = require('mongodb').Long;
subscriptions.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        sub_id: {
            $gt: long.fromString(String(BigInt("223211232421412323324235435645356") - 1n)),
            $lt: long.fromString(String(BigInt("223211232421412323324235435645358") + 1n))
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        sub_id: 1
    }
}], {
    collation: {
        locale: "en_US",
        numericOrdering: true
    }
})
```

But the results i am getting are empty, i am wondering why it wont work? Maybe there is another way to work with `bigint`in mongo? I tried Google it but couldn't find anything except the code above.

Comment: [Decimal128](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/index.html)?

Comment: It still give me empty results, i think there is no way to do it with mongo.

Comment: Create an example dataset in https://mongoplayground.net/

Comment: somehow when i test on PG it works, https://mongoplayground.net/p/BwCUigh54Eo ... cant understand why.

Comment: In the playground you're not using bigint. You're comparing strings instead.